# Why the message doesn't appear above the accordion in Chrome?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying the new HTML5 validations and when I try to use the `required` attribute inside the `<input>` tag, the message *This field can't be blank* is not being displayed correctly. The problem appears when I insert a this `<input>` tag within a Twitter Bootstrap accordion and I try to submit the form with Google Chrome (v. 23).

With other browsers, the message appear above the accordion (I tested it in Firefox 17) but with Chrome, half of the message is hidden because of the accordion.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdxnT/) shows this issue.

How can I solve the problem? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was you had an `overflow:hidden;` property set in your `div#collapseOne` element, so you just need to set it to `visible`.

```
#collapseOne {
    overflow:visible;            
}
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdxnT/1/).