# jQuery Chosen div falls behind Twitter Bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I'm using the jQuery Chosen plugin inside a Twitter Bootstrap accordion. The problem that I have is that the dropdown menu of the Chosen plugin appears 'under' the `div` of the accordion menu. I tried to set the `z-index` to a higher value, but that didn't do the trick.

I made an example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8BAZY/1/

If you click on the `select` box you'll see that the menu appears under the `div`. How can I let the dropdown appear ontop of the accordion div, so I can see all the results?

Comment: this is some conflict with twitter-bootstrap ... if you comment bootstrap's js script you don't get this ...

Comment: The problem is because `.collapse` has `overflow: hidden`. Obviously absolutly positioned chosen dropdown will be clipped.

Comment: @dfsq You're right. It seems to works when i remove the `overflow: hidden`. It also doesn't seem to be giving any unwanted behavior. Could you please add it as an answer?

Comment: I made a similar question with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043673/why-the-message-doesnt-appear-above-the-accordion-in-chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem is because `.collapse` has `overflow: hidden`. Obviously
>   absolutly positioned chosen dropdown will be clipped. – dfsq 2 days
>   ago

Answer (score 6):

More info on this chosen issue is here
https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/86

One solution based on the suggestions given on that page by PilotBob
http://jsfiddle.net/8BAZY/6/

```
$(function() {
    var els = jQuery(".chzn-select");
    els.chosen({no_results_text: "No results matched"});
    els.on("liszt:showing_dropdown", function () {
            $(this).parents("div").css("overflow", "visible");
        });
    els.on("liszt:hiding_dropdown", function () {
            $(this).parents("div").css("overflow", "");
        });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I moved on to using select2 instead.

Answer (score 6):

It's not elegant, but you can do it like this:

```
#collapseOne {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#collapseOne.in {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

This will make sure it gets clipped when collapsed, and visible when shown.

Answer (score 6):

Solution posted by Sudhir worked for me except it had one minor issue: When you have more than one choosen control inside the div and you expand other choosen while there is one already expanded, the new one will fall behind the accordion. This is because the first dropdown sets the overflow to hidden after 2nd one is expanded. Here is the fix.

```
$(function () {
   fixChoosen();
});

function fixChoosen() {
   var els = jQuery(".chosen-select");
   els.on("chosen:showing_dropdown", function () {
      $(this).parents("div").css("overflow", "visible");
   });
   els.on("chosen:hiding_dropdown", function () {
      var $parent = $(this).parents("div");

      // See if we need to reset the overflow or not.
      var noOtherExpanded = $('.chosen-with-drop', $parent).length == 0;
      if (noOtherExpanded)
         $parent.css("overflow", "");
   });
}
```

Comment: I added a few more lines and made it work for me. Thank you +1

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with the Chosen select getting a width of 0px when I was using it within a Bootstrap collapse element. This was easily fixed by adding `width:100%!important;` to the element `.chosen-container` in my CSS.

Comment: I had the same problem, but inside a bootstrap tab. Your solution works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change chosen.min.css or chosen.css :

```
.chosen-container{position:relative;
```

To :

```
.chosen-container{position: fixed;
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed it with the css line :

```
div.chosen-container-active{
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For new versions

```
.chosen-drop {
    z-index: 999999 !important;
}
```

for old versions

```
.chzn-drop {
    z-index: 999999 !important;
}
```

This worked for me "chosen1.3" and "bootstrap3.1", this solution **may** need some considerations, but I did not face any issues. Please read more https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/86

Answer (score 1):

Simply this worked for me:

```
.chosen-container.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop {
    position: relative;
}
```

I didn't invent it myself, obtained the solution via https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/86

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by putting overflow: auto on the parent