# Accordion with jQuery "Chosen" select: height becomes too large before snapping back

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, jquery-chosen

I'm using [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) inside a [Twitter Bootstrap Accordion](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse). I've solved the issue of the Chosen dropdown being clipped by the accordion body using answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14915337/419956). This still leaves me with one other issue: the accordion will slide down and grow in height, but **it'll grow too much** and after that **snap back** to the appropriate height.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXdwY/1/) demonstrates the issue. Here's an illustration of the problem:

[image: Screenshots of stage collapsed, expanding, and expanded]

.

### Code to reproduce the issue

To [reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/nXdwY/1/) this issue I've used the following code:

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"> <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#body1">First group</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="body1">
            <div class="box-content">
                <span>Body content!</span>
                <select multiple="multiple" class="chzn-select">
                    <option>Option A</option><option>Option B</option><option>Option C</option><option>Option D</option><option>Option E</option><option>Option F</option><option>Option G</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Activating the chosen dropdown with this code:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chzn-select').chosen();
});
```

And using this CSS for fixing mentioned overflow issue as well as some debugging aid:

```css
/* Styles for visualizing the problem: */
body, .box-content { padding: 10px; }
.accordion-body { background-color: #EEE; }
.accordion-heading { background-color: #DDD; }

/* Required to make sure the chosen select can expand outside the box: */
.collapse.in { overflow: visible; }
```

.

### Things I've tried:

There are several things I've tried to resolve this:

- Different variations of solving the overflow issue. However, I noticed that my problem occurs [regardless of the overflow issue](http://jsfiddle.net/nXdwY/2/).
- Using a regular select. This obviously [works around my issue](http://jsfiddle.net/Wx2XP/), but is not truly a solution.
- Setting `height: 0` and `display: none` on the Chosen select. [No effect](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb24e/).

.

### Question

How can you prevent the accordion to grow too much height in the first place, and make it grow to the correct size straight away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with little bit of js, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXdwY/6/). The relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chzn-select').chosen();

    $(".box-content") .hover(function(){
        $(".chzn-container .chzn-drop") .css({"display":"block"});
    },function(){
        $(".chzn-container .chzn-drop") .css({"display":"none"});
    });    
});
```

Alternatively but along the same lines, you can use the following CSS to fix the problem:

```
.accordion-body .chzn-container .chzn-drop { display: none; }
.accordion-body[style="height: auto;"] .chzn-container .chzn-drop { display: block; }
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsSmd/) for a demo.

Comment: there was a bug in prev fiddle i jave updated it , its working according to your demand

Comment: You helped me fix it! I've taken the liberty of adding a slight (css-based) variation that I ended up using, so I can credit your answer (instead of adding my own answer). Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: Hmm, this does break things in IE8, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

there is a very simple CSS solution:

**.chosen-container** gets class **chosen-with-drop** when the dropdown is opened.

```
.chosen-container:not(.chosen-with-drop) .chosen-drop {
    display: none;
}
```

i had the same problem today and this is my tested solution.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Chris' answer; if you're implementing with bootstrap accordions you can easily just hide the list while the collapse event is firing so that it's height isn't calculated.

```
.collapse, .collapsing {
  &:not(.in) .chosen-drop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```